# Yesterday - in Redshift & PostgreSQL - date addition compatibility

Tags: amazon-redshift

Attempting to write queries that will be compatible with both PostgreSQL and Amazon Redshift.

*Reason*: Syncing data from PG to RS to perform complex queries, but in dev/QA environments budget (and DB size) dictates to stay with PG only.

*Request*: return yesterday's date

**In PostgreSQL:**

```
SELECT DATE((NOW() - '1 DAY'::INTERVAL));
```

**In Redshift:**

```
SELECT DATE(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()));
```

*Problem*: Neither works in the other platform.

Is there a compatible way to achieve requested action?
ORM is an option we'd like to avoid.

Comment: Testing on one platform and deploying another platform is a dangerous approach.  At the very least, once the PostgreSQL tests pass, you should be running ***at least*** the same tests against RedShift too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following works in Postgres and Redshift:

ANSI standard SQL:

```
SELECT current_date - interval '1' day;
-- 2018-06-19 00:00:00
SELECT current_timestamp - interval '1' day;
-- 2018-06-19 13:40:06.509337+00
```

Postgres (and I believe Redshift as well) also supports the alternative (non-standard) interval syntax: `interval '1 day'`

Or more compact (not 100% ANSI SQL but works in both):

```
SELECT current_date - 1;
-- 2018-06-19 00:00:00
SELECT current_timestamp - 1;
-- 2018-06-19 13:40:06.509337+00
```